# Website stuck on "waiting<websiteName>" using IE 11 browser but ok in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-chrome, iis-7, internet-explorer-11

I have a weird encounter after i deploy a website in intranet. I published it successfully on a remote server. I tried opening it in Chrome: it works perfectly,
but using Internet Explorer 11, the webpage can't be seen. In the upper portion of the website(the title) it says "Waiting " and it doesn't seems loading.

Other information: my application is in ASP.NET, .NET framework 4, iis 7

Answer (score 0):

This is something to do with the javascript being referenced on the webpage, the version of IE doesn't support thus it must be updated